# I want to take user input in Spark dataframe but giving error ['list' object is not callable]

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

[I can not take any input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00mUv.png)I have a schema.

```
schm = StructType([
    StructField("ID", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("fixed_credit_limit", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("credit_limit", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("due_amount", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("created_date", StringType(), True),
    StructField("updated_date", StringType(), True),
    StructField("agent_name_id",IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("rfid_id", StringType(), True),
])

input=[(13158,100,100,0,'05/29/2021 11:01:31','05/29/2021 11:01:31',5,'862b4497-577f-47f9-8725-dd6c397ce408')]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(input, schema)
```

I want to take the user input of `agent_name_id` but it gives the error `['list' object is not callable]`
how can I take the user input of `agent_name_id`.

Comment: that looks like pyspark not pandas

Comment: please solve it with pyspark.....I tried it with pandas by converting it.

Comment: There is no error on this part of the code. Please add where you are getting the error (where you are trying to get the `agent_name_id` from user input.

Comment: As per stackoverflow guide, please try not to post code in image.  But your error is you are overwriting `input` function by the list data `input=[(13158,100,100,...)]`. You can rename the variable for the data to something other than `input` and you should be good. Make sure to restart the kernel to clear the variable.  
A little tip is when you see the variable gets green color on notebook, it is likely it is reserved keyword.  You should see black color just like `df1 = ...` on notebook.